# Webgl - Rendering depth to texture returns gl.INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION in Safari

Tags: webgl, framebuffer, depth-buffer, render-to-texture, shadow-mapping

If you look at the following snippet in Safari (taken from https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shadows.html), you will notice it looks different than in other browsers, because the depth texture is always completely black:

```js
'use strict';

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_depth_texture');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need WEBGL_depth_texture');  // eslint-disable-line
  }

  // setup GLSL programs
  const textureProgramInfo = webglUtils.createProgramInfo(gl, ['3d-vertex-shader', '3d-fragment-shader']);
  const colorProgramInfo = webglUtils.createProgramInfo(gl, ['color-vertex-shader', 'color-fragment-shader']);

  const sphereBufferInfo = primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(
      gl,
      1,  // radius
      32, // subdivisions around
      24, // subdivisions down
  );
  const planeBufferInfo = primitives.createPlaneBufferInfo(
      gl,
      20,  // width
      20,  // height
      1,   // subdivisions across
      1,   // subdivisions down
  );
  const cubeBufferInfo = primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(
      gl,
      2,  // size
  );
  const cubeLinesBufferInfo = webglUtils.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: [
      -1, -1, -1,
       1, -1, -1,
      -1,  1, -1,
       1,  1, -1,
      -1, -1,  1,
       1, -1,  1,
      -1,  1,  1,
       1,  1,  1,
    ],
    indices: [
      0, 1,
      1, 3,
      3, 2,
      2, 0,

      4, 5,
      5, 7,
      7, 6,
      6, 4,

      0, 4,
      1, 5,
      3, 7,
      2, 6,
    ],
  });

  // make a 8x8 checkerboard texture
  const checkerboardTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, checkerboardTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,                // mip level
      gl.LUMINANCE,     // internal format
      8,                // width
      8,                // height
      0,                // border
      gl.LUMINANCE,     // format
      gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
      new Uint8Array([  // data
        0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
        0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
        0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
        0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
        0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
      ]));
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  const depthTexture = gl.createTexture();
  const depthTextureSize = 512;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,      // target
      0,                  // mip level
      gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, // internal format
      depthTextureSize,   // width
      depthTextureSize,   // height
      0,                  // border
      gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, // format
      gl.UNSIGNED_INT,    // type
      null);              // data
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  const depthFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, depthFramebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      gl.FRAMEBUFFER,       // target
      gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,  // attachment point
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,        // texture target
      depthTexture,         // texture
      0);                   // mip level

  function degToRad(d) {
    return d * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  const settings = {
    cameraX: 6,
    cameraY: 5,
    posX: 2.5,
    posY: 4.8,
    posZ: 4.3,
    targetX: 2.5,
    targetY: 0,
    targetZ: 3.5,
    projWidth: 1,
    projHeight: 1,
    perspective: true,
    fieldOfView: 120,
  };
  webglLessonsUI.setupUI(document.querySelector('#ui'), settings, [
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'cameraX',    min: -10, max: 10, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'cameraY',    min:   1, max: 20, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'posX',       min: -10, max: 10, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'posY',       min:   1, max: 20, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'posZ',       min:   1, max: 20, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'targetX',    min: -10, max: 10, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'targetY',    min:   0, max: 20, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'targetZ',    min: -10, max: 20, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'projWidth',  min:   0, max:  2, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'projHeight', min:   0, max:  2, change: render, precision: 2, step: 0.001, },
    { type: 'checkbox', key: 'perspective', change: render, },
    { type: 'slider',   key: 'fieldOfView', min:  1, max: 179, change: render, },
  ]);

  const fieldOfViewRadians = degToRad(60);

  // Uniforms for each object.
  const planeUniforms = {
    u_colorMult: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1],  // lightblue
    u_color: [1, 0, 0, 1],
    u_texture: checkerboardTexture,
    u_world: m4.translation(0, 0, 0),
  };
  const sphereUniforms = {
    u_colorMult: [1, 0.5, 0.5, 1],  // pink
    u_color: [0, 0, 1, 1],
    u_texture: checkerboardTexture,
    u_world: m4.translation(2, 3, 4),
  };
  const cubeUniforms = {
    u_colorMult: [0.5, 1, 0.5, 1],  // lightgreen
    u_color: [0, 0, 1, 1],
    u_texture: checkerboardTexture,
    u_world: m4.translation(3, 1, 0),
  };

  function drawScene(projectionMatrix, cameraMatrix, textureMatrix, programInfo) {
    // Make a view matrix from the camera matrix.
    const viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // set uniforms that are the same for both the sphere and plane
    // note: any values with no corresponding uniform in the shader
    // are ignored.
    webglUtils.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_view: viewMatrix,
      u_projection: projectionMatrix,
      u_textureMatrix: textureMatrix,
      u_projectedTexture: depthTexture,
    });

    // ------ Draw the sphere --------

    // Setup all the needed attributes.
    webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, sphereBufferInfo);

    // Set the uniforms unique to the sphere
    webglUtils.setUniforms(programInfo, sphereUniforms);

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    webglUtils.drawBufferInfo(gl, sphereBufferInfo);

    // ------ Draw the cube --------

    // Setup all the needed attributes.
    webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, cubeBufferInfo);

    // Set the uniforms unique to the cube
    webglUtils.setUniforms(programInfo, cubeUniforms);

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    webglUtils.drawBufferInfo(gl, cubeBufferInfo);

    // ------ Draw the plane --------

    // Setup all the needed attributes.
    webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, planeBufferInfo);

    // Set the uniforms unique to the cube
    webglUtils.setUniforms(programInfo, planeUniforms);

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    webglUtils.drawBufferInfo(gl, planeBufferInfo);
  }

  // Draw the scene.
  function render() {
    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // first draw from the POV of the light
    const lightWorldMatrix = m4.lookAt(
        [settings.posX, settings.posY, settings.posZ],          // position
        [settings.targetX, settings.targetY, settings.targetZ], // target
        [0, 1, 0],                                              // up
    );
    const lightProjectionMatrix = settings.perspective
        ? m4.perspective(
            degToRad(settings.fieldOfView),
            settings.projWidth / settings.projHeight,
            0.5,  // near
            10)   // far
        : m4.orthographic(
            -settings.projWidth / 2,   // left
             settings.projWidth / 2,   // right
            -settings.projHeight / 2,  // bottom
             settings.projHeight / 2,  // top
             0.5,                      // near
             10);                      // far

    // draw to the depth texture
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, depthFramebuffer);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, depthTextureSize, depthTextureSize);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    drawScene(lightProjectionMatrix, lightWorldMatrix, m4.identity(), colorProgramInfo);

    // now draw scene to the canvas projecting the depth texture into the scene
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    let textureMatrix = m4.identity();
    textureMatrix = m4.translate(textureMatrix, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    textureMatrix = m4.scale(textureMatrix, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    textureMatrix = m4.multiply(textureMatrix, lightProjectionMatrix);
    // use the inverse of this world matrix to make
    // a matrix that will transform other positions
    // to be relative this this world space.
    textureMatrix = m4.multiply(
        textureMatrix,
        m4.inverse(lightWorldMatrix));

    // Compute the projection matrix
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const projectionMatrix =
        m4.perspective(fieldOfViewRadians, aspect, 1, 2000);

    // Compute the camera's matrix using look at.
    const cameraPosition = [settings.cameraX, settings.cameraY, 7];
    const target = [0, 0, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];
    const cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);

    drawScene(projectionMatrix, cameraMatrix, textureMatrix, textureProgramInfo);

    // ------ Draw the frustum ------
    {
      const viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);

      gl.useProgram(colorProgramInfo.program);

      // Setup all the needed attributes.
      webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, colorProgramInfo, cubeLinesBufferInfo);

      // scale the cube in Z so it's really long
      // to represent the texture is being projected to
      // infinity
      const mat = m4.multiply(
          lightWorldMatrix, m4.inverse(lightProjectionMatrix));

      // Set the uniforms we just computed
      webglUtils.setUniforms(colorProgramInfo, {
        u_color: [0, 0, 0, 1],
        u_view: viewMatrix,
        u_projection: projectionMatrix,
        u_world: mat,
      });

      // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
      webglUtils.drawBufferInfo(gl, cubeLinesBufferInfo, gl.LINES);
    }
  }
  render();
}

main();
```

```css
@import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
.gman-widget-value {
  min-width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div id="uiContainer">
    <div id="ui">
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script  id="3d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_projection;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_textureMatrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_projectedTexcoord;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  vec4 worldPosition = u_world * a_position;

  gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * worldPosition;

  // Pass the texture coord to the fragment shader.
  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;

  v_projectedTexcoord = u_textureMatrix * worldPosition;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script  id="3d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// Passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_projectedTexcoord;

uniform vec4 u_colorMult;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_projectedTexture;

void main() {
  vec3 projectedTexcoord = v_projectedTexcoord.xyz / v_projectedTexcoord.w;
  bool inRange =
      projectedTexcoord.x >= 0.0 &&
      projectedTexcoord.x <= 1.0 &&
      projectedTexcoord.y >= 0.0 &&
      projectedTexcoord.y <= 1.0;

  // the 'r' channel has the depth values
  vec4 projectedTexColor = vec4(texture2D(u_projectedTexture, projectedTexcoord.xy).rrr, 1);
  vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord) * u_colorMult;
  float projectedAmount = inRange ? 1.0 : 0.0;
  gl_FragColor = mix(texColor, projectedTexColor, projectedAmount);
}
</script>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script  id="color-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;

uniform mat4 u_projection;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_world;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrices.
  gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * u_world * a_position;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script  id="color-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script><!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-lessons-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/primitives.js"></script>
```

I've based my own implementations on this, and run into the same issue. WebGL returns a gl.INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION when calling getError after a call to gl.clea or to gl.drawElements. I assume something is wrong with the setup of the framebuffer, but nothing I tried helps. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Safari pre version 15 you need to setup a color attachment even if though the sample doesn't use it

first create an RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE color attachment the same size as the depth texture

```
  const dummy = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, dummy);
  gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,
      gl.RGBA,
      depthTextureSize,
      depthTextureSize,
      0,
      gl.RGBA,
      gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      null,
  );
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then attach it to the framebuffer

```
  const depthFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, depthFramebuffer);
  
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      gl.FRAMEBUFFER,       // target
      gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,  // attachment point
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,        // texture target
      depthTexture,         // texture
      0);                   // mip level

  // ---- added ----
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
      gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      dummy,
      0,
  )
```

Unfortunately this is not a bug in Safari. It's a reflection of unfortunate choices of the [OpenGL ES 2.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) which says

> ### 4.4.5 Framebuffer Completeness
>
> ...
>
> #### Framebuffer Completeness
>
> ...
>
> The framebuffer object target is said to be framebuffer complete if it is the window-system-provided framebuffer, or if all the following conditons are true:
>
> In this subsection, each rule is followed by an error enum in bold
>
> ...
>
> - The combination of internal formats of the attached images does not violate an **implementation-dependent** set of restrictions.
>
>   `FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`

In other words, in OpenGL ES 2.0 **NO COMBINATIONS OF FRAMEBUFFER ATTACHMENTS ARE REQUIRED TO WORK!!!!!!!**

[The WebGL spec itself](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/) added the requirement that 3 combinations are required to work

> ### 6.8 Framebuffer Object Attachments
>
> ...
>
> The following combinations of framebuffer object attachments, when all of the attachments are framebuffer attachment complete, non-zero, and have the same width and height, must result in the framebuffer being framebuffer complete:
>
> - `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` = `RGBA`/`UNSIGNED_BYTE` texture
> - `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` = `RGBA`/`UNSIGNED_BYTE` texture + `DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` = `DEPTH_COMPONENT16` renderbuffer
> - `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` = `RGBA`/`UNSIGNED_BYTE` texture + `DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` = `DEPTH_STENCIL` renderbuffer

So, following the 2 specs, even though the `WEBGL_depth_texture` extension adds depth textures, none of them are required to work as attachments in framebuffers with or without any other attachments!!!

Yes, you read that right. The WEBGL_depth_texture extension spec says you can create them and attach them. The OpenGL ES 2.0 spec says they are not required to work as attachments or rather that it's up to the implementation whether any combinations work. WebGL lists 3 combinations that are required to work but those 3 combinations do not include depth textures, only depth renderbuffers.

Fortunately it appears they do work everywhere if you add an RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE color attachment.

On a positive note, OpenGL ES 3.0 and WebGL2 list many more combinations that are required to work.

Comment: While we're on spec trivia, another unfortunate OpenGL ES 2.0 spec choice, according to the spec an implementation can support only textures with dimensions of 64 pixels or less and still be considered a passing implementation. Note that I know of no WebGL implementions with a minimum less then 2048 so in reality it's fine but the spec says 64 is all that's required. Fortunately OpenGL ES 3.0 raised that min to 2048.

Comment: Whoever came up with this should be sacked! I wasn't even aware that having these combinations could be a requirement at all...
The 64 pixel idea also seems a bit extreme. If you would have this low texture size limit, I would think it's a very special case and you wouldn't care about compliance anyways.

Comment: Agreed. In their defense OpenGL ES 2.0 was designed back when feature phones were still a thing.